# Firefox context menu doesn't disappear and stays there

Tags: firefox

Very annoying problem.

I can't get to close the Firefox context menu, the one you get when you click on any webpage with a right button mouse click.

For example when I'm on Nautilus File Manager on Ubuntu and I right click I am able to make it disappear by a left mouse click anyplace different from the menu.

This doesn't happen with Firefox.. I only get to close it with the `Esc` key, but it is annoying.

Any solution?

Firefox is version 54.0 64 bit on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

**EDIT 1**

output of `free -h`

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          3,7G       1,6G       2,1G       203M       106M       689M
-/+ buffers/cache:       842M       2,8G
Swap:         3,8G         0B       3,8G
```

Output of `swapon -s`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition   3986428 0   -1
```

Comment: If you restart FF with extensions disabled, is the problem gone?

Comment: The problem persists

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works there. That may tell us if it's a software problem on your HDD/SSD. Tell me what version Live, and if it worked or not.

Comment: ps: how much RAM? how much swap? Are you using any custom themes or icon sets?

Comment: Are you using Firefox 54? It happens when I upgraded from 51.0 which worked well.. 4GB RAM

Comment: Yes, I'm also using FF 54. They made some big changes in 54, that allows multiple process to speed things up, but at a cost of more memory usage. You didn't say how much swap. Show me the `terminal` output of `free -h` and `swapon -s`. Please edit that output into your questions, and then ping me with `@heynnema` or I may miss the update. Did you try the Live DVD? Themes/icons sets?

Comment: @heynnema Hi, a bit late but I updated my question according to your suggestions thanks

Comment: @heynnema No Themes/ icons added to Firefox, I noticed the issued time ago, when I had just installed it. Didn't try the Live DVD, I have no possibility.

Comment: You might try upgrading your Ubuntu... you're at 14.04... and we're currently at 17.04... you're only 3 years behind...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It annoyed me, too, so I've had to find out it's caused by *ui.popup.disable_autohide=true*. You can reset it in [about:config](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/about-config-editor-firefox).

Comment: This worked on macOS 10.14, Firefox 67.0.4